# Type of a value captured in a lambda from a reference type, not using generalized capture

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++17, decltype

When I compile the following program (https://wandbox.org/permlink/fl6yrLYI2sRrZJHP)

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <typename...> class WhichType;

int main() {
    const auto& integer = 0;
    [integer]() {
        WhichType<decltype(integer)>{};
    }();
}
```

Why does the compiler say that `decltype(integer)` is `const int&`?  My understanding was that this should have been `const int` and `decltype((integer))` should have resolved to `const int&`.

In other words my understanding was that the lambda would resolve to a struct like this

```
struct Lambda {
public:
  explicit Lambda(const int& integer_) : integer{integer_} {}
  void operator()() const {
    WhichType<decltype(integer)>{};
  }

  const int integer;
};
```

Why does `decltype(integer)` resolve to a reference type?  Is this just another case of `decltype` behaving specially?  Similar to the referenced type and the actual type distinction in structured bindings?

Comment: Visual C++ 2017 reports `const int`. MinGW g++ 7.3.0 reports `const int&`.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior appears to be mandated by the standard. It appears to be a specific exception for `decltype()` within a lambda:

```
8.1.5.2 Captures               [expr.prim.lambda.capture]

...

14 Every occurrence of decltype((x)) where x is a possibly parenthesized id-
expression that names an entity of automatic storage duration is treated as if x
were transformed into an access to a corresponding data member of the closure
type that would have been declared if x were an odr-use of the denoted entity.

Example:

void f3() {
   float x, &r = x;
   [=] { // x and r are not captured (appearance in a decltype operand is not an odr-use)
      decltype(x) y1; // y1 has type float
      decltype((x)) y2 = y1; // y2 has type float const& because this lambda is
                             // not mutable and x is an lvalue

      decltype(r) r1 = y1;  // r1 has type float& (transformation not considered)
      decltype((r)) r2 = y2; // r2 has type float const&
 };
}
— end example ]
```

The key words there appear to be "transformation not considered".

Answer (score 1):

There are two relevant rules here.

What does it mean to refer to something in a lambda? That's in [expr.lambda.prim.capture](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda#capture-11), emphasis mine:

> Every *id-expression* within the *compound-statement* of a *lambda-expression* **that is an odr-use** of an entity captured by copy is transformed into an access to the corresponding unnamed data member of the closure type.

And then, what does `decltype` mean? That's in [[dcl.type.simple]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.simple#4):

> For an expression `e`, the type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as follows:
>   - [...]
>   - otherwise, if `e` is an unparenthesized *id-expression* or an unparenthesized class member access, `decltype(e)` is the type of the entity named by `e`. If there is no such entity, or if `e` names a set of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed;

`decltype(integer)` is not an odr-use of `integer`, so this is just the type of `integer`, which is `const int&`. This is actually the most normal meaning of `decltype` - it's just the type of the variable (it's just in a context where you might think it's the type of the invented capture - although in that case, the type of the invented capture is just `int`, not `const int`).

Where you're going wrong is how you're naming the member variable of your synthesized type for the lambda. More accurate would be:

```
int main() {
    const auto& integer = 0;
    struct __lambda {
        int __integer;

        auto operator() const {
            WhichType<decltype(integer)>{}; // NB: still integer, not __integer, because not an odr-use
        };
    }

    __lambda{integer}();
}
```

---

There is a separate rule specifically for [`decltype((x))`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda#capture-14), which would have `decltype((integer))` still being `const int&` in this case actually but for a different reason, but that rule is the subject of [CWG 1913](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1913) and that wording has been removed from the latest working draft.